# Mysql Event Scheduler : Table Does not exist error , despite existing

Tags: mysql, events, scheduler

Looking for some advice please :

I have a MySQL 5.6 Event scheduler set up as below:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`10.0.0.%` EVENT `update_reports` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 3 MINUTE STARTS '2015-10-16 13:01:20' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO update_reports:BEGIN
    DECLARE triggered datetime DEFAULT SYSDATE();
    DECLARE started datetime DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE status tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0;

    # LOGIC
    IF wait_for_processing('reports.processing') THEN
        SET started = SYSDATE();

        # SET SESSION VARIABLES
        SELECT enable_logging(false);
        SELECT enable_debug_timers(true);
        SET @reporting_from = '2013-03-01 00:00:00';
        IF (needs_update()) THEN
            SELECT update_usage_data();
            SET status = 1;
        ELSE
            SET status = 2;
        END IF;

        SELECT free_for_processing('reports.processing');
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO ref.event_logs
    SELECT
        'reports',
        'update_reports',
        triggered,
        started,
        SYSDATE(),
        null,
        status;
END update_reports
```

However, in the MySql Error log I am receiving this error:

```
2015-10-16 13:37:20 29327 [ERROR] Event Scheduler: [root@10.0.0.%][reports.update_reports] Table 'reports.reporting_statsevent_logsuser_seen' doesn't exist
2015-10-16 13:37:20 29327 [Note] Event Scheduler: [root@10.0.0.%].[reports.update_reports] event execution failed.
```

Permissions on the database and tables show root@10.0.0.% to have full permissions.

Could anyone please share any troubleshooting steps I can take to understand why the event scheduler cannot access the tables, yet the queries work fine when carried out in MySql Workbench.

Thank you.

Comment: Check carefully for typos in the table name.

Comment: I don't see any mention of that table in the event definition. Are you accessing a view that uses it, or is it in one of the functions you call?